# Multiple bitmap blits too fast for system?

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

I've got a an image (inside of a scroll viewer) that is 2,000 x 2,000 pixels. In a while loop I'm calling the following code 5 times:

```
writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(CleanVegMap);
image.Source = writeableBitmap;
DrawDinos2d();
```

What is happening is that the image 'freezes' for about 10 seconds and then redraws the fifth, and final image. The feeling is that the system can't handle it.

If I just draw each image outside of the while loop from a pull-down menu they update properly.

The `DrawDino2d()` method draws about 48 pixels on each bitmap. Just for clarification, the `DrawDino2d()` is below:

```
        public void DrawDinos2d()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MainWindow.Dinosaurs.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Location.Count; j++)
                SetPixel(writeableBitmap, (int)MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Location[j].X, (int)MainWindow.Dinosaurs[i].Location[j].Y, System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(127, 255, 255, 0));
        }

    }// DrawDinos2d

        public void SetPixel(WriteableBitmap wb, int x, int y, System.Windows.Media.Color color)
    {
        var pixelRect = new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1);
        var pixelBuffer = new byte[4];
        wb.CopyPixels(pixelRect, pixelBuffer, 4, 0);
        pixelBuffer[0] = (byte)(pixelBuffer[0] * (1F - color.ScA) + color.B * color.ScA);
        pixelBuffer[1] = (byte)(pixelBuffer[1] * (1F - color.ScA) + color.G * color.ScA);
        pixelBuffer[2] = (byte)(pixelBuffer[2] * (1F - color.ScA) + color.R * color.ScA);
        wb.WritePixels(pixelRect, pixelBuffer, 4, 0);
    }
```

Here's an image of (extreme detail) of the 'dinos' being updated on the map:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to invalid regions and delayed painting.  When performing animation, you often have to disable double-buffering or force immediately update of the display.

Comment: If it is the case that the routine is very processor heavy consider multithreading some of the routines to expect better performance.

Comment: Welcome to while loops never mind delayed painting. **Edit** also, set pixel is horrible for most purposes when it comes to efficiency

Comment: hmm if DrawDino2d works on some fields, it would be good practice to pass them as parameters to the method.
Anyway, I think more peices of code are needed in order to understand your problem

Comment: How would I disable double-buffering or force an immediate update of the display? It's only in a while loop for testing purposes... eventually it's in an infinite loop until keypress (updating the position of the dinosaurs in the simulations).

Comment: "In a while loop I'm calling the following code 5 times". And there you are blocking the UI thread. Call that code in the `Tick` handler of a DispatcherTimer.

Comment: I'm not finding any examples (except having to do with time) for using a 'Tick' handler of a DispatcherTimer. Can you point me in the right direction?